# i can't access iframe element from my java script using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**here is my code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
     <html>  
     <head>  
     <title>Form</title>  
    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
     </head>  
     <body>
    <iframe id="tryf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

        <p id="tryd">Hello World!</p>

    </iframe>
     <script>

        alert($('#tryf').contents().find('#tryd').html())

     </script>  
     </body>  
     </html>
```

**i got "undefined" in the alert box ,, i want to get "Hello World!"**
[image: the output when i open the page]

Comment: `inline frame` or `iframe` is used to embed another document within the current HTML document and can not be used as a `<div>`

Comment: You can't put inline content directly in an `iframe` like that; the output of your JS code is correct. If you look at the document in your screen shot you can even see that the iframe content is empty

Comment: thanks, can i make iframe embed HTML page and still access this HTML page elements ?

Comment: @AmrRady put `<p id="tryd">Hello World!</p>` in a file lets say `main.html` and call it by iframe like `<iframe id="tryf" src="main.html" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"><iframe>` and it will work just fine.